# Is the .gitignore file universal/global, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I'm a noob to RoR, so any help/clarification is appreciated.

Is the .gitignore file in Rails universal/global to all of Rails, or does each project/app have its own .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default `.gitignore` is created when you create a new Rails app. That file tells git to ignore the things that are in a default Rails app that should probably be ignored.

If there are other files that should be ignored in your specific app, you can make changes to the `.gitignore`. If you're not using git, you can delete the file entirely.

It's basically there to encourage best practices, but is in no way required to run a Rails app.

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` is a Git file, it has nothing to do with Rails.

A `.gitignore` file will apply to the directory it is in and any subdirectories. You can create `.gitignore` files in subdirectories to have them only apply to those subdirectories and their descendants.

Answer (score 0):

There's a .gitignore_global file in your ~/ directory that every git instance references.
Git is independent of rails.
the .gitignore file is restricted to the initialized repository.